# Difference between kernel source code (kernel.org) and linux-source (in software center)

Tags: 11.10, kernel, software-center, kernel-modules

What is the difference between kernel code downloaded from http://www.kernel.org and the one downloaded from Software Center `linux-source` package?

Which one is better for writing a device driver?

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu kernel has a number of patches to tweak it.  To see exactly what ones, you will want to check out the Ubuntu kernel with GIT and review the history.  You can do this with:

```
git clone git:///kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-precise.git linux
cd linux
gitk
```